# What metric does AWS Lambda, specifically for Node.js runtime use to determine the Max Memory used?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to determine how large an array would be in memory for when my function executes. Determining the size of the array is easy but I am not seeing a correlation to the size of my array to the Max Memory used that gets recorded at the end of a Lambda execution.

There is no apparent coloration after inspecting `process.memoryUsage()` before and after setting the array as well as the Max Memory used reported by the Lambda. I can't find a good resource that indicates how/what Lambda actually uses to determine the memory used. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: This may help https://medium.com/@raupach/choosing-the-right-amount-of-memory-for-your-aws-lambda-function-99615ddf75dd

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that does not really help. I understand the relationship between CPU and memory and how to choose the correct value. What I don't understand is how AWS Lambda allocates memory inside the function it self as it differs  from the what Node.js reports. I want to know how AWS calculates the amount of memory used.

Comment: It probably counts the total memory consumed by the container. Try examining the contents of /proc/meminfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I used the following code and increased the amount of array values to get a correlation. Three tests were done on each max value of the array. Lambda was set at 1024MB. Each array element is 10 chars/bytes long.

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);


async function GetContainerUsage()
{
     const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('cat /proc/meminfo');
    // console.log(stdout);
    let memInfoSplits = stdout.split(/[\n: ]/).filter( val => val.trim());
    // console.log(memInfoSplits[19]); // This returns the "Active" value which seems to be used
    return Math.round(memInfoSplits[19] / 1024);
}


function GetMemoryUsage()
{
    const used = process.memoryUsage();

    for (let key in used)
        used[key] = Math.round((used[key] / 1024 / 1024));

    return used;
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => 
{
    let max = event.ArrTotal;
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        arr.push("1234567890"); //10 Bytes
    }

    let csvLine = [];
    let jsMemUsed = GetMemoryUsage(); 
    let containerMemUsed = await GetContainerUsage(); 


    csvLine.push(event.ArrTotal);
    csvLine.push(jsMemUsed.rss);
    csvLine.push(jsMemUsed.heapTotal);
    csvLine.push(jsMemUsed.heapUsed);
    csvLine.push(jsMemUsed.external);
    csvLine.push(containerMemUsed);  

    console.log(csvLine.join(','));
    return true;
};
```

This output the following values used in the CSV:

```
Array Count, JS rss, JS heapTotal, JS heapUsed, external, System Active, Lambda reported usage
1,30,7,5,0,53,54
1,31,7,5,0,53,55
1,30,8,5,0,53,55
1000,30,8,5,0,53,55
1000,30,8,5,0,53,55
1000,30,8,5,0,53,55
10000,30,8,5,0,53,55
10000,31,8,6,0,54,56
10000,33,7,5,0,54,57
100000,32,12,7,0,56,57
100000,34,11,8,0,57,59
100000,36,12,10,0,59,61
1000000,64,42,39,0,88,89
1000000,60,36,34,0,84,89
1000000,60,36,34,0,84,89
10000000,271,248,244,0,294,297
10000000,271,248,244,0,295,297
10000000,271,250,244,0,295,297
```

Which if graphed becomes: 
[image]

So at 10 Million elements the array is assumed to be 10mil*10bytes = 100MB. There must be some overhead I am missing somewhere as there is about 200MB used elsewhere. But at least there is a clear linear correlation, which I can now work with.

Answer (score 6):

This question made me curious myself, so I decided to run some tests to see how memory allocation works inside an AWS Lambda container.

**Test 1**: Create array with 100,000 elements in memory

Memory size: 128MB

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    console.log(process.memoryUsage());
    return 'done';
};
```

**Result**: 56 MB

```
2019-04-30T01:00:59.577Z    cd473d5b-986c-436e-8b36-b114410c84cf    { rss: 35299328,
  heapTotal: 11853824,
  heapUsed: 7590320,
  external: 8224 }
REPORT RequestId: 2a7548f9-5d2f-4060-8f9e-deb228730d8c  Duration: 155.74 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB
```

**Test 2**: Create array with 1,000,000 elements in memory

Memory size: 128MB

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    console.log(process.memoryUsage());
    return 'done';
};
```

**Result**: 99 MB

```
2019-04-30T01:03:44.582Z    547a9de8-35f7-48e2-a53f-ab669b188f9a    { rss: 80093184,
  heapTotal: 55263232,
  heapUsed: 52951088,
  external: 8224 }
REPORT RequestId: 547a9de8-35f7-48e2-a53f-ab669b188f9a  Duration: 801.68 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 99 MB
```

**Test 3**: Create array with 10,000,000 elements in memory

Memory size: 128MB

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    console.log(process.memoryUsage());
    return 'done';
};
```

**Result**: 128 MB

```
REPORT RequestId: f1df4f39-e0fc-4b44-8f90-c3c0e3d9c12d  Duration: 3001.33 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB 
2019-04-30T00:54:32.970Z f1df4f39-e0fc-4b44-8f90-c3c0e3d9c12d Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

I think we can pretty confidently say that the memory used by the lambda container does go up based on the size of an array in memory; in our third test we ended up maxing out our memory and timing out. My assumption here is that the process that controls the execution of the lambda also monitors how much memory that execution acquires; likely by `cat /proc/meminfo` as trognanders suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to do a similar test my self.

Comment: @DR. Can you please post the results of your own test?

Comment: @dashmug I did, see below.

Comment: @DR. "Above" you mean. :-) Thank you. That's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Capacity specification for FaaS vs PaaS**

The whole idea of doing computing with lambda functions(FaaS) is that least bother on capacity planning. Now, given that its not possible for the cloud provider to default a lot of choices, memory settings and timeouts are some settings AWS uses to configure the function. Apparently, if you test it out you may see that memory settings are not just determining the memory but also the CPU compute capacity. This is as quoted by AWS -

> Lambda allocates CPU power linearly in proportion to the amount of memory configured. At 1,792 MB, a function has the equivalent of 1 full vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits per second)

Ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html

Hence, its not just enough to consider runtime memory footprint, but also for CPU speed with which it executed and finishes the function.
AWS does not call out what capacity or CPU/Memory/Server Type/IOPS they use in these containers and neither they show that usage in any CW metrics like an EC2 instance. 
Hence we need to choose memory setting based on testing.

Each lambda(nodejs) will have its own memory footprint and dedicated set of node module dependencies. Hence, each one needs to load and performance tested to tune the memory and timeout settings and cannot be planned upfront.

**General research observation**
With any standard nodejs based lambda function, which has logging and does just hello world, deployed without a VPC

- 128 MB may show an execution time of say 150+ ms and a billing of
  200ms for 128 MB
- 256 MB may show an execution time of say 80+ ms and
  a billing of 100ms for 256 MB

Lower memory setting does not mean lower cost essentially and hence fine tuning based on load & performance test is the best way to determine the memory setting that can be used.

Attributes like timeout, is purely based on how long the function takes to complete the activity, which can be way high up for batch job operations(say 10m) vs a webservice which expects a quick response(say 10s). Timing out earlier instead of waiting on any long pending dependencies are important to avoid high billing in case of high throughput APIs. In case of API, slow timeout can result in alternate containers(functions) to spin up to scale for new requests which can also impact the number of IPs being allocated within the subnet which hosts the function(in case function runs within a vpc ).

Lambda limits on ENI and IPs or maximum lambda concurrency within a account/region is important factors to consider while planning for the capacity.
Ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, I am completely aware of how Lambda works and all those facts are known. Regarding the Capacity planning statement, I don't totally agree, I my case for example, I had to do a small-ish ETL job and have to dedupe some data, there are various methods available I know. But I choose to rather load the data in memory rather than spin any 'server' based stores to help with the querying. So I had to know how much data I can load before hitting the limits, to determine if it was a viable option, thus this question.

Comment: Lambda memory is ephemeral, based on your need here it might be good to do the etl processing in chunks, where you can decide on the chunk size and easily work around the lambda limits. Alternately, keeping the data in s3 or dynamo table are also good serverless options where you operate only on the small subset which you process in a transaction. I personally don’t architect for full in memory long term operations due to the risk of outages and inconsistencies it can cause to the overall integrity of data. Hope it helps.

Comment: The data is in S3, using Athena to query the set, then creating a hash map, where the key is a Hash of the unique fields for that row and the ID is the value. Then when inserting new data, I check if it already exists in my Hash map, if so, use the ID returned to update, else insert. How would you do this any differently/more efficiently? I am using Lambda now, until we scale and the set becomes to large, then I would move to Fargate most likely.

Comment: if you have a method of doing it more efficiently that fits my use case I would really be eager to year as my method is O(n) at least regarding memory usage. Which isn't superb, but I can live with that.